# Configure Ice Warp with Google Cloud DNS

Tags: email-server, google-cloud-dns

I'm trying to configure my Ice Warp mail server to work with our Google Cloud DNS.  A lot of our emails are ending up in the spam folders after we send them  I've configured google cloud with the required

A, MX, CNAME, SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records

Also have set up a PTR record in a reverse lookup zone which is the reverse lookup of the IP addy of our Ice warp server.

Ran a test on Google Toolbox and received this outcome.  Can anyone give me some info as to what needs to be setup on the server or in DNS to get it right?  I don't want to guess at things...just want to get it right

[screen capture of Google Toolbox result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pY3Q.jpg)

Comment: Lots of things can make your messages go into spam for example the content of the message (spammy links) or one of the most common ones that the message is not authenticated. You might have configured SPF,DKIM and DMARC but these authentication methods might break during the delivery flow. Please share the message headers of one message that landed in the spam folder I'm interested in the Authentication-Results header. I also recommend you to take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59127735/sendgrid-is-always-sending-my-emails-to-the-spam-folder-of-the-recipient/59141358#59141358

Comment: Ernesto...Thanks for your input.  I was failing in the DKIM on Gmail.  Fixed that now Gmail works...Hotmail has us blocked and won't remove us.

Comment: Glad to hear you found and fix the authentication problems.Nothing much to do with Hotmail other than asking your known recipients to mark your messages as not spam. I believe the form to request a removal from Microsoft blacklist is https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportrequestform/8ad563e3-288e-2a61-8122-3ba03d6b8d75

Answer (score 1):

The warning message that you are getting in the screenshot that you have sent is because you are allowing only a specific ip address in your spf record. It will basically allow the emails from that particular ip to come in. If you are using a google domain, then please follow [1](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en) to setup spf records, otherwise please ignore that warning message. 
For setting up the DKIM and DMARC record, please follow [2](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/dnssec-advanced#spf-dkim-dmarc).Please note that the article [2](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/dnssec-advanced#spf-dkim-dmarc) has further sub links once you click on DKIM and DMARC.  You can take the help of [3](https://cloud.google.com/dns/records/) to verify if your domain is properly setup to configure DKIM and DMARC records. This has to be done once you have completed the steps in article [2](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/dnssec-advanced#spf-dkim-dmarc)
You can find information about managing records in Cloud DNS in article [3](https://cloud.google.com/dns/records/)

Comment: This helped.  Appreciate it.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To have properly working mail server you need to add A, [MX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record), [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail), and [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) records to Cloud DNS for your domain (as it was suggested by *@Ernesto U*) and PTR record which maps the IP address to the name of your mail server (and resolved name of your mail server should maps to the same IP). **Don't forget to** [setup DKIM](https://support.icewarp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000302847-How-To-Setup-DKIM-For-Your-Domain) in configuration of your mail server in addition to DNS record.

In my opinion, this [online diagnostic tools](https://mxtoolbox.com) could be very helpful to check proper configuration of your mail server as well as DNS records.

Also, I'd recommend to you check your public IP to be sure that it isn't listed in any block lists [here](https://talosintelligence.com) and [here](https://www.dnsbl.info).

If you still have a problem after all checks, please update your question with full headers of some test email and DNS records for your domain.

Comment: DKIM was one of the culprits.  Even though it had been set up it was done wrong